# Can I define a structure data type in CMake?

Tags: cmake

The dominant data type in CMake is string, and almost all the variables in CMake is based on string. I was wondering whether it is possible to create a structure similar to C/C++ structure. I give the following example to illustrate my question:

with C/C++ , we can define structure in this way:

```
struct targetProperty
{
   std::string folder_name;
   std::string lib_name;
   std::string exe_name;
   std::string lib_type;
};
```

In CMake, we can emulate this structure by using LIST:

```
set(targetProperty "the location for the folder")
list(APPEND targetProperty "the name of the lib")
list(APPEND targetProperty "the name of the executable")
list(APPEND targetProperty "the type of the lib")
```

But it is not as clear as `struct targetProperty` in C/C++, and I was wondering whether there are other smart alternatives. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can emulate structures with the variable name postfixed with the field name:

```
set(targetProperty_folder_name "the location for the folder")
set(targetProperty_lib_name "the name of the lib")
```

Another approach is what CMake uses to emulate named parameters in the commands:

```
list(APPEND targetProperty FOLDER_NAME "the location for the folder")
list(APPEND targetProperty LIB_NAME "the name of the lib")
```

then you can parse the list with the [CMakeParseArguments](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/CMakeParseArguments.html) module.

In both cases you can write setter and getter macros to automate the operations.

For a sophisticated framework solution see [cmakepp/Objects](https://github.com/toeb/cmakepp/blob/master/cmake/object/README.md).

Answer (score 7):

If you need to associate structure with CMake targets(executables, libraries, custom ones), the simplest way is to use CMake properties:

```
define_property(TARGET PROPERTY folder_name
    BRIEF_DOCS "The location for the folder"
    FULL_DOCS "The location for the folder"
)
define_property(TARGET PROPERTY lib_name
    BRIEF_DOCS "The name of the lib"
    FULL_DOCS "The name of the lib"
)

... # Define other structure field as properties


# Add some CMake target
add_custom_target(my_target1 ...)

# Associate structure with target
set_target_properties(my_target1 PROPERTIES
    folder_name "dir1"
    ... # set other properties
)

# Use properties
get_target_property(my_target1_folder my_target1 folder_name)
message("folder_name for my_target1 is ${my_target1_folder}")
```

CMake properties can also be associated with source directories, which allows some sort of inheritance.

For more info see `define_property` command [desctiption](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/define_property.html). Or ask more specific question.